# OpenCL kernel definition error clBuildProgram(CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE)?

Tags: c, opencl

running an openCl application it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: clBuildProgram(CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE)
```

this is the kernel definition,
one error is in the log2 function,

another error is in `char* bits = &(char_array[64*(n/m)*(index-1)+it*64]);`

another error is in `max[it] = *count`

and the last error is in `if(max[i] > *result){*result = max[i];}`.

could you tell me how to correct the definition? Thanks

```
__kernel void vadd(
    __global char* char_array,
    int m,
    int n,
    __global long* result)
{ 

    int index = get_global_id(0);
    int max_n = n/m;
    if(index == m-1){
        max_n = n - (n/m)*(m-1);
    }

    int max[ max_n ];
    int offset = log2(m);
    for (int it=0; it < max_n; it++)
    {
        char* bits = &(char_array[64*(n/m)*(index-1)+it*64]);
        int count=0;
        for(int i=offset; i<=64; i++)
        {
            if(bits[i]=='0'){
                count++;
            }else{break;}
        }
        max[it] = count;
    }

    *result = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<max_n;i++)
    {
        if(max[i] > *result){*result = max[i];}
    }
    *result = *result +1;
}
```

Comment: Would you perhaps simply quote the entire build log? The error messages will save us a lot of time trying to work out what's not right.

Comment: }catch (cl::Error err) {
        std::cout << "Exception\n";
        std::cerr
        << "ERROR: "
        << err.what()
        << "("
        << err_code(err.err())
        << ")"
        << std::endl;

this is what i have in the host, and the error reported is all that is given at runtime

Comment: You can get a detailed compile log by querying the `CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG` with [clGetProgramBuildInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetProgramBuildInfo.html).

Answer (score 1):

A mistake on this line:

```
char* bits = &(char_array[64*(n/m)*(index-1)+it*64]);
```

is that `char* bits` when declaring a local variable actually means `__private char*`, whereas `char_array` is defined as `__global char*`. You'll want to make sure that `bits` uses the same type.

The others aren't immediately obvious to me, but I recommend you add the complete kernel build output to your question as this will help narrow it down.